# MS Test in Visual Studio 10 creates TestResults folder depending on the computer name

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have VS 2010 and MS Test. When I run a unit test it fails when I do:

var path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

path here is:

```
C:\RepoTest\yadProcessXcellerator\sources\TestResults\Administrator_MyComputerName 2014-06-25 16_32_06\Out\ModuleService\TestData
```

How can another employee ever run this unit test with the testdata which is in an individual path?

I can not set my build output to the above path...

How can I workaround that problem?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is the problem? Why does the test fail?

Comment: Why does TestResults contain the computername? When I commit my tests to svn another developer checking out the tests will have failing tests, because this TestResults path with my computername does not exists on his pc...